# USPS/WooCommerce not packaging items together

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, usps

I have a WordPress site which uses WooCommerce. The USPS shipping plugin is installed, however the two shipping options that I have enabled (first class package service and priority mail) are selected through WooCommerce (USPS WooCommerce Services).

The issue is that when I add two or more items to my cart the shipping charges double. That is, each item is being treated as it's own package. I have selected the "pack items together option" in WooCommerce, have added a package type, and have specified dimensions for the product.

Any ideas as to what I might need to change/specify o get things working properly? Also, I want to limit the amount packed together to five.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the USPS Shipping Plugin from xAdapter, then what is going on is that you're using the free version of it, the free version only lets you add 2 items in a box, if you want to add more in one box, basically they force you to buy it. In my opinion the best solution in this case if you want to save a few bucks is to use "Woocommerce Services" along side with "Jetpack".

Regards.